# React add transitions/animations to wizard form

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions

I am really struggling adding a fade-in or transition effect to a rendered multi-step form/components on React (without Router).

I've tried using `CSSTransitionGroup`.

This is the form container and a rendered component (in this case, the last one).

```js
class FormStart extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
     step: 1,
     phone: "",
     firstname: "",
     lastname: "",
     city: "",
     distance: ""
   }
    this.goToNext = this.goToNext.bind(this);
  }

  goToNext() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    if (step !== 4) {
      this.setState({ step: step + 1 });
      if (step == 3) {
    
        const values = {
          phone: this.state.phone,
          firstname: this.state.firstname,
          lastname: this.state.lastname,
          city: this.state.city,
          distance: this.state.distance
        };
        // submit `values` to the server here.
      }
    }
  }

  handleChange(field) {
    return (evt) => this.setState({ [field]: evt.target.value });
  }

  render(){
    switch (this.state.step) {
    case 1:
      return <FormButton
        onSubmit={this.goToNext}
      />;
    case 2:
      return <FormStep1
        onSubmit={this.goToNext}
        phone={this.state.phone}
        firstname={this.state.firstname}
        lastname={this.state.lastname}
        onPhoneChange={this.handleChange('phone')}
        onFirstNameChange={this.handleChange('firstname')}
        onLastNameChange={this.handleChange('lastname')}
      />;
    case 3:
      return <FormStep2
        onSubmit={this.goToNext}
        city={this.state.city}
        distance={this.state.distance}
        onCityChange={this.handleChange('city')}
        onDistanceChange={this.handleChange('distance')}
      />;
    case 4:
      return <FormSuccess/>;
    }
  }
}

export default FormStart;


class FormSuccess extends Component {

  render(){

   var successMessage;

  successMessage = 
  <section id="success">
   <p>HellO</p>
  </section>

    return (
      <div>
          <CSSTransitionGroup
               transitionName="success"
               transitionEnterTimeout={500}
               transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
         {successMessage}
          </CSSTransitionGroup>
      </div>
   )
   }
 }

export default FormSuccess;
```

I tried to add a `CSSTransitionGroup` component to `FormSuccess`, by triggering on a props.state or by enclosing the component call on `FormStart`. CSS styles are correct, because they were working earlier when I had another component call structure. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[react-transitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-transitions)** it is an npm package and fairly easy to use. It worked for me when I was using **[react-wizard-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-wizard-form)**